# NodeJS: Real time client notification about last upload time

Tags: node.js, express

User can upload data via my /upload HTTP endpoint 
(I code it using NodeJS/Express). 
I need to update Web page (ReactJS) in real time to show the last upload time.
I tried to use SSE for this and hit the problem.

This is working code which uploads the data to server:

```
 const upload = async (req, res) => {
    try {
       // upload logic is here ..
    return res
      .status(200)
      .send('Success!');

  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).send(e.message);
  }
};
```

To update Web page in real time with timestamp of last upload I tried to inject the following SSE function into upload() function above inside the try{} block just before the return statement:

```
function sendSSE(response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
    Connection: 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  });

  const content = JSON.stringify(Date.now());
  response.write(content);
  response.write('\n\n');

}
```

I got the error:

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: You might want to consider using [an existing library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sse) to encapsulate your SSE calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send headers twice.

When you call `res.status(200)` and when you call `response.writeHead(200, ...)`, you're forcing the output of the status line and the headers.  This isn't something you can do.

Simply, don't do that.  Get rid of your `res.status(200).send('Success!');` bit.